# SourceMap read failed

Tags: visual-studio-2017, winjs, typescript-2.5

I have a WinJS-UWP-Application, where I use TypeScript 2.5. I just upgraded from VS2015 to VS2017. When I want to debug my WinJS-UWP-Application the Breakpoints inside my .ts-Files are not noted, because the SourceMap isnt read properly. I didn't change any configuration of the project. 
In the output I get this message:

> SourceMap
>   ms-appx://8d7814f6-7286-4475-8ed8-be1c489c2253/js/main.js.map read
>   failed: The URI prefix is not recognized..
>   My CompilerOptions are:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
```

The min and target version of the application are: `10.0.14393.0`
Do I need to setup anything else in VS2017?

**EDIT:**
Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new UWP WinJS-App in VS 17 with Min and Target Version: `10.0.14393.0`
2. Remove the js\main.js
3. Add a main.ts file in the js folder
4. Create a tslib folder and insert the winjs.d.ts inside [For example from DefinetlyTyped]
5. Add the following code inside the main.ts:

```js
/// <reference path="../tslib/winjs.d.ts"/>

WinJS.UI.processAll().then(() => {
    let div: HTMLDivElement = document.createElement("div");
    let label: HTMLLabelElement = document.createElement("label");
    label.textContent = "Hello from the TypeScript-Side";
    div.appendChild(label);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

6. Add a new tsconfig.json from the VS17 template.
7. Start the app with the AnyCPU Configuration

Expected result:
Inside the App you see the text:

> Content goes here!
>   Hello from the TypeScript-Side

In the ouput you see these two messages:

> 'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (MSAppHost/3.0)'. 
>   SourceMap ms-appx://32fb2864-03cf-4387-8a05-6c65a66c5a48/js/main.js.map read failed: The URI prefix is not recognized..

**EDIT 2:**
The content of the main.js.map:

```js
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "main.js",
  "sourceRoot": "",
  "sources": [ "main.ts" ],
  "names": [],
  "mappings": "AAAA,2CAA2C;AAE3C,KAAK,CAAC,EAAE,CAAC,UAAU,EAAE,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC;IACvB,IAAI,GAAG,GAAmB,QAAQ,CAAC,aAAa,CAAC,KAAK,CAAC,CAAC;IACxD,IAAI,KAAK,GAAqB,QAAQ,CAAC,aAAa,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC,CAAC;IAC9D,KAAK,CAAC,WAAW,GAAG,gCAAgC,CAAC;IACrD,GAAG,CAAC,WAAW,CAAC,KAAK,CAAC,CAAC;IACvB,QAAQ,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,WAAW,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC;AACnC,CAAC,CAAC,CAAC"
}
```

**EDIT3:**
TypescriptBuild-Settings:

```
TypeScript version: 2.5
Compile on save: Yes
Allow implicit 'any' types: Yes
Keep comments in JavaScript output: Yes
Generate declaration files: No
Generate source maps: Yes
Specify root directory of source maps: $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)
Specify root directory of TypeScript files: $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)
Emit on error: No
```

If I delete the `tsconfig.json`, the source maps are created correctly. But i need the `tsconfig.json` for a few other options, so deleting it is not an option!

Comment: Please try to delete the SourceMap and rebuild it again to see if you still face this issue.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFTSorry for the late response: I allready tried this. There is still the same issue

Comment: If so, please upload a [mcve]. I would need it to help you diagnose this issue.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT See my edit to reproduce the problem

Comment: I want to check your SourceMap. Please post it here.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT See my edit

Comment: The value of sourceRoot should not be empty. E.g, `"sourceRoot":"F:/WorkingSample/2017_10/2017_1030/TestTSWinJS/TestTSWinJS/"`. In general, this value will be generated automatically by visual studio. So, you might need to check your visual studio's settings or other things.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT The TypescriptBuild-Setting for the sourcemap is setted to: $(MSBuildProjectDirectory). Its the default. The same in VS15 where it works

Comment: It it worked well in VS 15. I think this issue was more related to VS 2017. You could first try to reinstall the [TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258). After that, if you still face this issue, you might need to repair your VS 2017.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I Will try these steps... But we have the same problem in every PC of the office

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I followed your steps... Same result. See my edits pls

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround which fixes the problem for the moment. I don't know why this works, but if you add the line:

```
"mapRoot": "js/"
```

it works correctly.

This only works for the default directory setup!